# Illegal prime numbers: What is it exactly?

Tags: security, primes

I don't know if you know this situation, but sometimes I'm just browsing from one Wikipedia page to the next. So I also saw [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_prime) about illegal primes. I read the article and it sounds really interesting, but I didn't really understand what it's really about.

As far as I understand illegal primes are prime numbers that can be somehow use to generate malicious code? But how? Are there any other examples than the one in the article?

And what is the real life use of them?

Comment: I just read the article, and I'm not sure what part you didn't understand. It seems clearly written and described to me. Take any "illegal" code (malicious or not) and represent it as a number or prime number; the result is still against certain laws.

Comment: Even though I think it's an interesting question, I don't think it's on topic for this site.

Comment: Though I answered, I'm voting so close as this really has nothing to do with security or programming.

Comment: How about legal numbers? 299,792,458 metres per second - it's not just a good idea, it's the law!

Comment: As a programmer who has bumped into intellectual property issues, I'm amazed how many people think that something like this is off topic.  Admittedly, this one is at the fringes but it's helpful for programmers to know where the boundaries of law are if it's possible their code might be declared illegal.  For example, if you come up with a protocol that makes it easy to form spontaneous mesh networks you might have the next great IM app - or the RIAA might make your code illegal if one possible use is to share files. If we can't discuss this here, then where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article uses the DeCSS program as an example.  That program decrypts DVDs which, according to US Federal law and international treaties, is a crime.  It is therefore illegal to posses or distribute that specific source code.

However, the source code can be expressed as a series of binary numbers like...

`11100101 10001000 00001000 00000000 01001010 11110010`

Which is `252372412549874` in decimal.  If the binary code above were illegal, then the decimal number `252372412549874` would be an "illegal number".  An illegal prime number is one in a subset of illegal numbers that happens to be prime.

The fact that something like DeCSS code is also an ordinal value that represents an integer conflicts with the notion of it being illegal.  After all, how can the abstract concept of a specific integer be illegal?  The term "illegal number" is an oxymoron designed to point out that laws overreach when they attempt to control human artifacts that happen to coincide with abstract concepts.  It is the *act* of decrypting DVDs that can be enforced, not the possession or knowledge of an integer on the number line.

Answer (score 4):

No, they aren't numbers that can generate malicious code.

The point is that certain types of code are illegal to distribute in the United States; for example, code that is meant to break copy-protection on movies.  Activists like to make the point that it's ridiculous to ban the distribution of code, which is just a bunch of letters and numbers, after all.  People like to do things like print the code on a t-shirt and wear it, or sing it in a song, to point out how those restrictions don't make sense.

Illegal numbers are numbers that are encodings of such illegal code.  In theory, writing down such a number and passing it around is a crime.  Illegal primes are just an interesting subset of such numbers -- since there are databases of prime numbers and large prime numbers are useful, it's easy to imagine that illegal primes would be innocently published -- so then has a crime been committed?

It's really just a thought experiment to show how ridiculous those laws are.

Answer (score 2):

Computers operate on numbers. A file is just a really big number.

Sometimes, those numbers are prime.

In real life, their uses are more political than practical.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply an [illegal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_number) which happens to be prime.